# How to hide the public API of dependencies (.jar libraries) in Android module?

Tags: java, android, api, public

I am creating an Android library which depends on another library I created. However when I create an aar/jar file of my new library, I can still reach the public classes from the library I depend on.

Is there any way to make the dependencies visible internally only?

Comment: An idea (I didn't try it): create another jar that includes these libs and wrap them with your own wrappers which will provide public API to your original project. Now include only this jar in your project, are these APIs still available even when they become transitive dependencies ?

Comment: Why is it necessary to hide these classes? Usually the answer to such questions is that: a) it is not necessary, and hiding the classes will be an inconvenience to future users; or b) your library is improperly encapsulated, and the solution is to reorganise the library.

Comment: @alfasin I tried that, I don't understand why, but the API of the internal jar is visible outside of the library.

Comment: @Zwander To be more specific, the reason to do what I described is that I have a low level library, which I don't want to be public. Instead, what I want is to wrap it in a high-level API with reduced functionality.